# Ubuntu 18.04 Server for a 4k laptop display?

Tags: display-resolution

My laptop has a 4K screen. Display specs: 15.6”, 4K UHD (3840 x 2160), IPS. I need to use Ubuntu Server but the font size in terminal is barely readable (very small).

How could I change the resolution? Or, how could I increase the font size?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You can reconfigure the `console-setup` package:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

It will ask you questions about the language/font and size to use for TTY consoles. Note that there are some limitations because of VGA graphics standards. Check `man console-setup` for more information on those limitations.

Comment: @LeonardoA.Cortez If this answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer text.

Answer (score -2):

To zoom in/increase text size in terminal try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> 
To zoom out/decrease text size <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

**EDIT:**
This is only useful if you are using the terminal on ubuntu desktop to access the server.

Comment: He's using Ubuntu Server not Gnome Terminal.

Comment: fair point, I assumed he was remoting into it because I did not see why he would be using a 4k monitor plugged into the server.  This is not a fair assumption, my bad.

Comment: I have a dual boot on my inspiron 7577 laptop. I need Ubuntu Server to test some programs I made in a controlled environment. Usually I use Ubuntu desktop!

Comment: ah, now that is a setup that makes sense to me. thanks for satisfying my curiosity seemed a strange thing to be doing otherwise.