# Ubuntu 20.04 server ting text on 1440 screen

Tags: display, text

I use a new 1440 gaming monitor for a Windows desktop but also feed in 2x Ubuntu servers and one Debian server (no GUIs on any of them) through a 4K KVM switch. The text on the three Linux devices is too small to read. It was fine with my old 1080 monitor. Any way to fix?

Comment: No, not really. Server editions were never designed for UHD screens. But there are tweaks you can apply: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087186/ubuntu-18-04-server-for-a-4k-laptop-display

Comment: Perfect worked on all three Linux boxes - thanks.